# Is it safe to use data.auth.uid?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm using a google cloud function to handle firestore data deletion like so:

```
exports.deleteAccount = https.onCall(
    async (data, auth) => {
        const uid = data.auth.uid;
        // ...
       
    }
);
```

My firestore database is structured so that user documents id's are the user's uids. Is it safe to use the uid provided in data.auth.uid to handle the deletion? I.e can a different or not authed user provide a different uid?

The function is called in a flutter app like so:

```
HttpsCallable callable =
        FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(region: 'asia-southeast1')
            .httpsCallable('deleteAccount');
    await callable();
``
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was referring to first gen documentation:

```
// Saves a message to the Firebase Realtime Database but sanitizes the text by removing swearwords.
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // ...
});
```

But the function used was a second gen cloud function. Based on the documentation it should be used like this:

```
exports.addmessage = onCall((request) => {
  const uid = request.auth.uid;
  // ...
});
```

So when using the second generation cloud function, it is ok to use data.auth.uid (written as request.auth.uid in the documentation)

Answer (score 3):

> Is it safe to use `data.auth.uid`?

##### Short answer:

Yes, **but** there is an error in your code.

You should use `auth.auth.uid` instead of `data.auth.uid` because you do `https.onCall(async (data, auth) => {...});`. I suggest to use the name `context` for the second variable passed to the callback instead of `auth`, as shown in the examples in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?gen=1st#node.js) for 1st gen Callable Cloud Functions.

##### Longer answer:

"With Callable Cloud Functions, Firebase Authentication tokens, FCM tokens, and App Check tokens, when available, are automatically included in requests", as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?gen=1st#node.js).

So you can be sure that `context.auth.uid` returns the `uid` of the user who calls the Cloud Function (if the user is authenticated in your Flutter app, of course).

If a user calls the Cloud Function while not being authenticated you can send back an error as shown below, which will stop the Cloud Function execution.

```
exports.deleteAccount = https.onCall(
    async (data, context) => {

        if (!context.auth) {
         // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
         throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
           "failed-precondition",
           "The function must be called while authenticated."
         );
        }

        const uid = context.auth.uid;
        // ...
       
    });
```

Comment: Hi! That was actually a typo. I've tried using context.auth but context seems to be undefined? Can I still use data.auth.uid?

Comment: I understand that you use Cloud Function 1st gen. Then if you do `https.onCall(
    async (data, context) => {...})` you **must** use the `context` parameter (the 2nd one passed to the callback), as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?hl=en&authuser=0&gen=1st#write_and_deploy_the_callable_function): "`context` parameters represent **user auth information**"

Comment: Your comment pointed me in the right direction! I'm actually on 2nd gen but was referring to documentation for the first gen. Thank you for your help!